# remove special characters from a string if they are on their own and not part of a word

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to remove special characters from a string if they are on their own and not part of a word.

example would be

```
var str = "This i$ @ gr£@t t£$t !: i think i$nt it%";
```

should become

```
var newstr = "This i$ gr£@t t£$t i think i$nt it%";
```

Comment: You could use `\B[^\w\s]+\B`

Comment: `str = str.replace(/\s\W+\s/g, '');`

Answer (score 4):

Use this pattern:

```js
var str = "This i$ @ gr£@t t£$t !: i think i$nt it%";
var result = str.replace(/(?:^|\s+)\W+(?:\s+|$)/g," ");
document.write(result);
```

Comment: wont work if the special characters are at the beginning or end of the string. Ex. `'@ abc #'`.

Comment: @Shafizadeh this is now incorrect, i want to keep the special chars if they are included in a word

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald Edited ..!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
^[^\w\s]+\B\s*|\s+[^\w\s]+\B(\s)\s*|\s*\B[^\w\s]+$
```

Substitute with `$1`. This will collapse the whitespace around the removed word into a single space.

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/oE4xL3/1)

Downside: if you aren't happy with which characters are considered "special characters", you have to modify all *three* occurences of the character class `[^\w\s]`.